# Проблема с созданием JSON из массива

Tags: php, json

Имеется следующий JSON-код, который появляется путём обработки массива:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "username": "xxx",
    "userid": 1,
    "subscriptions": [{
        "name": "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive",
        "acquired": 1469815540,
        "expiring": 2147483647
    }, {
        "name": "Unknown",
        "acquired": 1469815540,
        "expiring": 2147483647
    }]
}
```

Массив появляется примерно следующим образом:

```
$info['subscriptions'][$i]['acquired'] = $res[$i]['acquired'];
$info['subscriptions'][$i]['expiring'] = $res[$i]['expiring'];
```

Но нужно, чтобы JSON имел следующий вид:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "username": "xxx",
    "userid": 1,
    "subscriptions": {
        "1": {
            "name": "Auto",
            "acquired": 0,
            "expiring": 0
        },

        "2": {
            "name": "Manual",
            "acquired": 0,
            "expiring": 0
        }
    }
}
```

Уже не понимаю что делать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начиная с PHP 5.3 появилась опция [JSON_FORCE_OBJECT](http://php.net/manual/ru/json.constants.php#constant.json-force-object):

> Выдавать объект вместо массива при использовании неассоциативного
>   массива. Это полезно, когда принимающая программа или код ожидают
>   объект или же массив пуст.

Пример:

```
$someArray = [
    'hello' => [
        ['a' => 'b'],
        ['c' => 'd'],
    ],
];

echo json_encode($someArray, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Результат:

```
{
    "hello": {
        "0": {
            "a": "b"
        },
        "1": {
            "c": "d"
        }
    }
}
```

*(на самом деле, тут еще [`JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`](http://php.net/manual/ru/json.constants.php#constant.json-pretty-print), но дело не в нём)*

Answer (score 1):

В PHP элементы массива могут принимать числовые и строковые значения. В первом случае мы говорим об индексном массиве, во-втором - об ассоциативном. Вам нужно превратить числовой ключ в строку

```
$info['subscriptions']["$i"]['acquired'] = $res[$i]['acquired'];
$info['subscriptions']["$i"]['expiring'] = $res[$i]['expiring'];
```

Многое конечно зависит от способа преобразования массива в JSON, однако, начинать следует именно с типа ключа.

Comment: Хм. Странно. Сделал следующим образом: `$info['subscriptions']["$i"]['acquired'] = $res[$i]['acquired'];`, ничего в JSON-результате не изменилось. Может-быть как-то не так создаю JSON? Использую в конечном итоге `json_encode($info);`.

Comment: Следующий код <?php
$info = [];
$info['subscriptions'] = [];
$i = 1;
$info['subscriptions']["$i"]['acquired'] = 1469815540;
$info['subscriptions']["$i"]['expiring'] = 2147483647;
$i = 2;
$info['subscriptions']["$i"]['acquired'] = 1469815540;
$info['subscriptions']["$i"]['expiring'] = 2147483647;
echo "<pre>";
echo json_encode($info); выдает корректные ключи {"subscriptions":{"1":{"acquired":1469815540,"expiring":2147483647},"2":{"acquired":1469815540,"expiring":2147483647}}}

Comment: Ваш ответ как-бы я использовал, но он не подошёл, но вот @xEdelweiss написал мне про сий волшебный флаг и я охренел от жизни. К сожалению, два ответа пометить не получится. :(